# Laravel multiauth Gate not working for admin table

Tags: php, laravel

**In laravel multiauth I have two tables admin and users. When I create gate for users it is working but for admin it is not working ( always showing
403
Forbidden
).**

**auth.php**

```
'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],


'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ]
    ],
```

**AuthServiceProvider.php**

```
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        // 'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::define('user', function ($user, Blog $blog) {
            return true;
        });

        Gate::define('admin', function ($admin, Blog $blog) {
            return true;
        });
    }
}
```

**BlogController.php**

```
class BlogController extends Controller
{
    public function update(Request $request, Blog $blog){
        if (! Gate::allows('admin', $blog)) {
            abort(403);
        }

    dd('Working');
   }
}
```

In frontend controller when using user gate it is giving 403 unauthorized response if returns false from user gate or print working if returns true from gate which is working fine.
But for backend when I try to use admin gate it is always giving 403 unauthorized response
regardless of true or false

Answer (score 0):

```php
if (! Gate::forUser($request->user('admin'))->allows('admin', $blog)) {
    abort(403);
}
```